# Dart callback - passing asynchronous message to parent object

Tags: dart, timer, callback, message-passing

I am trying to pass data (*bool*) from a child class through a callback Function (*ondone*) provided by the parent class, which will be called in a periodic function with a boolean argument.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class Flow {
  MyTimer timer;
  bool done = false;
  Function ondone;

  Flow() {
    ondone = (bool b) => done=b;
  }

  void addtimer(int t) {
    timer = MyTimer(t, ondone);
  }

}

class MyTimer {
  final int time;
  int remaining;
  Function callback;
  Timer _timer;

  MyTimer(this.time, this.callback){
    remaining = time;
  }

  void run() {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 1), 
        (t) { 
          remaining--;
          if (remaining == 0) {
          _timer.cancel();
          callback(true);
    }
    });
  }
}
```

But I am unable to figure out if callback is being called or not, because print function (in main) is not printing anything which is wrapped in an *if expression*.

```dart
void main() {
  var flow=Flow();
  flow.addtimer(5);
  flow.timer.run();
  if(flow.done) print('Timer Finished..');
  print('I need to run while timer is working');
}
```

Passing data from child to parent in an imperative style is important for me (as a beginner).

Comment: Your `Timer.periodic` are just running `(t) => remaining--`. So `remaining` will just keep being smaller without anything else happening since you are not running any other code.

Comment: You are calling `run()` from `main()`. This method is then executed in its entirety including the `if`. So you are creating a `Timer` and then immediately checking `if (remaining == 0)` which will be `false` since you are setting it to `5`.

Comment: But how can i run print function from main after remaining==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `flow.timer.run()` invokes the `Timer` which executes asynchronously. Your next line of code tests `flow.done` immediately, and of course it is not done yet. If you do this:

```
  flow.timer.run();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 6));
  if (flow.done) print('Timer Finished..');
```

Then your `main` function will pause for 6 seconds by which time the `Timer` will be complete.

If you do want to wait for the delay, you could code as follows:

```
  Future<void> run() async {
    while (remaining > 0) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      remaining = remaining - 1;
    }
    callback(true);
  }
```

and call it as:

```
  await flow.timer.run();
```

**Edit:** If you want to run other code in `main` and then wait, you can do:

```
  var future = flow.timer?.run();
  print('Timer is running...');
  await future;
  if (flow.done) print('Timer Finished..');
```

Comment: Thanks. Works now. Is there a better way to implement this without Future.delaying manually

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to change run().

Comment: Lesson Learned. One needs to be more thoughtful about their asynchronous code.

Comment: But await blocks the main() function if I were to put more code after the await call. Is there a way without threading?

Comment: I added an example with `main` running other code before waiting.